# maximum limit for MongoDB 2.6 sort query

Tags: mongodb

sorting 2 millions of records using mongo sort is possible or not?

From the MongoDB Documentation, it is clearly mentioned that "When the sort operation consumes more than 32 megabytes, MongoDB returns an error."

But I have a requirement to sort huge number of records. How to do it?

Comment: Similar SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023622/overflow-sort-stage-buffered-data-usage-exceeds-internal-limit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible. The documentation states that 32MB limit is there only when MongoDB sorts data in-memory i.e. without using an index.

> When the sort operation consumes more than 32 megabytes, MongoDB
>   returns an error. To avoid this error, either create an index to
>   support the sort operation or use sort() in conjunction with limit().
>   The specified limit must result in a number of documents that fall
>   within the 32 megabyte limit.

I suggest that you add an index on the field on which you want to sort with `ensureIndex` command:

```
db.coll.ensureIndex({ sortFieldName : 1});
```

If you're sorting on multiple fields, you will need to add an [compound index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/) on the fields your sorting on (order of the fields in index matter):

```
db.coll.ensureIndex({ sortFieldName1 : 1, sortFieldName2 : 1});
```

Comment: If I create an index on _id field , then i will be able to sort any number of records without giving limit. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user3318102 index on _id is created automatically, so you don't need to create it. You are correct, you if you're sorting on _id field, you will not hit the 32MB limit.