# Overflow sort stage buffered data usage exceeds internal limit

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

Using the code:

```
all_reviews = db_handle.find().sort('reviewDate', pymongo.ASCENDING)
print all_reviews.count()

print all_reviews[0]
print all_reviews[2000000]
```

The count prints `2043484`, and it prints `all_reviews[0]`.

However when printing `all_reviews[2000000]`, I get the error:

> pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: database error: Runner error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33554495 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes

How do I handle this?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You're running into the 32MB limit on an in-memory sort:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Sort-Operations

Add an index to the sort field. That allows MongoDB to stream documents to you in sorted order, rather than attempting to load them all into memory on the server and sort them in memory before sending them to the client.

Comment: can we change this limit?

Comment: Better to declare an index so you don't need to sort in RAM: faster and more reliable, limited RAM usage rather than potentially unlimited. If you insist, turn your "find" into an aggregation (which can use 100MB of RAM to sort) and set allowDiskUse: true to tell the aggregation framework to spill to disk if it would exceed 100MB of RAM. Expect a severe performance penalty compared to just declaring an appropriate index. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#sort-memory-limit

Comment: Oh, that's of course the best solution, and only the sensible one. I was just interested in knowing *how* to change the limit.

Comment: Understood. The limit cannot be changed.

Comment: Actually, it can be changed. You need to run this command: `db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, internalQueryExecMaxBlockingSortBytes: <limit in bytes>})`. Source: http://askubuntu.com/questions/501937/how-to-increase-buffered-data-limit

Comment: Good to note for mongoose users that setting index:true on the prop in your schema will fix this problem ... mongoose will go through all your schemas and ensure that the fields are in fact indexes before starting the app ... that is unless you turn this behavior off with mySchema.set('autoIndex', false);

Comment: I have created an index on sorting field but still it giving me this "Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM" error may be because of I am applying match operation before sorting and according to mongo doc if you use match before sort operation it will neglect index and perform in memory sorting over all matched records.

Comment: If this is the accepted answer, then it should include information on how to add an index.

Comment: It's worth noting that you might see this error if you try to sort on a non-existent field (eg, a typo)

Answer (score 47):

As said by `kumar_harsh` in the comments section, i would like to add another point.

You can view the current buffer usage using the below command over the `admin` database:

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.runCommand( { getParameter : 1, "internalQueryExecMaxBlockingSortBytes" : 1 } )
{ "internalQueryExecMaxBlockingSortBytes" : 33554432, "ok" : 1 }
```

It has a default value of **32 MB(33554432 bytes)**.In this case you're running short of buffer data so you can increase buffer limit with your own defined optimal value, example 50 MB as below:

```
>  db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, internalQueryExecMaxBlockingSortBytes:50151432})
{ "was" : 33554432, "ok" : 1 }
```

We can also set this limit permanently by the below parameter in the mongodb config file:

```
setParameter=internalQueryExecMaxBlockingSortBytes=309715200
```

Hope this helps !!!

`Note`:This commands supports only after version 3.0 +

Comment: What is the way to set this limit permanently in the config file?  I have a 1 TB memory machine dedicated to mongo and I would like to permanently crank it up.

Comment: @SamanthaAtkins I have updated the answer to set this permanently in the config file.

Comment: @JERRY where to set permanently in rails. Rails 5/mongoid.yml ?

Comment: I found it. run at my terminal with : mongod and follow manual https://zocada.com/setting-mongodb-users-beginners-guide/

Answer (score 25):

solved with indexing

```
db_handle.ensure_index([("reviewDate", pymongo.ASCENDING)])
```

Comment: be sure to not use a sparse index, they are ignored if you sort on every document

Comment: For MongoDB version >= 3 use: `create_index` rather than `ensure_index` see here: https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/how-to-create-an-index-for-a-mongodb-collection-in-python-371

Answer (score 14):

If you want to avoid creating an index (e.g. you just want a quick-and-dirty check to explore the data), you can use aggregation with disk usage:

```
all_reviews = db_handle.aggregate([{$sort: {'reviewDate': 1}}], {allowDiskUse: true})
```

(Not sure how to do this in pymongo, though).

Comment: In pymongo would be `db_handle.aggregate(pipe, allowDiskUse=True)`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272699/cant-get-allowdiskusetrue-to-work-with-pymongo) for more info!

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript API syntax for the index:

```
db_handle.ensureIndex({executedDate: 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was necessary to fix nessary indexes in code and recreate them:

```
rake db:mongoid:create_indexes RAILS_ENV=production
```

As the memory overflow does not occur when there is a needed index of field.

**PS** Before this I had to disable the errors when creating long indexes:

```
# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.12
connecting to: test
> db.getSiblingDB('admin').runCommand( { setParameter: 1, failIndexKeyTooLong: false } )
```

Also may be needed `reIndex`:

```
# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.12
connecting to: test
> use your_db
switched to db your_db
> db.getCollectionNames().forEach( function(collection){ db[collection].reIndex() } )
```