# Can't get allowDiskUse:True to work with pymongo

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I'm running into the `aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)` error with mongodb aggregation using pymongo.

I was able to overcome it at first using the `limit()` option. However, at some point I got the

```
Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in." error.
```

Ok, I'll use the `{'allowDiskUse':True}` option. This option works when I use it on the commandline, but when I tried to use in my python code

```
result = work1.aggregate(pipe, 'allowDiskUse:true')
```

I get `TypeError: aggregate() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)` error. (that's in spite of the definition given at http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate: aggregate(pipeline, **kwargs)).

I tried to use runCommand, or rather it's pymongo equivalent:

```
db.command('aggregate','work1',pipe, {'allowDiskUse':True})
```

but now I'm back to the 'aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)' error

In case you need to know

```
pipe = [{'$project': {'_id': 0, 'summary.trigrams': 1}}, {'$unwind': '$summary'}, {'$unwind': '$summary.trigrams'}, {'$group': {'count': {'$sum': 1}, '_id': '$summary.trigrams'}}, {'$sort': {'count': -1}}, {'$limit': 10000}]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 60, accepted):

So, in order:

- `aggregate` is a method. It takes 2 positional arguments (`self`, which is implicitly passed, and `pipeline`) and any number of *keyword* arguments (which must be passed as `foo=bar` -- if there's no `=` sign, it's not a keyword argument). This means you need to call `result = work1.aggregate(pipe, allowDiskUse=True)`.
- Your error about maximum document size is inherent to Mongo. Mongo can never return a document (or array thereof) larger than 16 megabytes. I can't tell you why because you have given us neither your data nor your code, but it probably means that the document you're building as an end result is too large. Try decreasing the `$limit` parameter, maybe? Start by setting it to 1, run a test, then increase it and look at how big the result gets when you do that.

Comment: >>work1.aggregate(pipe, allowDiskUse=True). That did the trick, perfect, thank you

Comment: @Max Noel After adding the `allowDiskUse=True` I don't see the bson size 16mb limit issue anymore, however, I got another size error from the pymongo side:  `raise DocumentTooLarge("command document too large") pymongo.errors.DocumentTooLarge: command document too large` Have you experienced this?