# how to get the sum in embedded fields in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongoDB collection looks like this:

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('5b243611dba907285af051ee'),
u'cms_prescription_counts': {u'ABILIFY': 11,
                          u'ALLOPURINOL': 86,
                          u'ALPRAZOLAM': 45,
                          u'AMLODIPINE BESYLATE': 175,
                          u'AMLODIPINE BESYLATE-BENAZEPRIL': 12,
                          u'ATENOLOL': 62,
                          u'ATENOLOL-CHLORTHALIDONE': 53,
                          u'ATORVASTATIN CALCIUM': 19,
                          u'AZITHROMYCIN': 18}},
 {u'_id': ObjectId('5b243611dba90728sad51ee'),
  u'cms_prescription_counts': {u'ABILIFY': 11,
                          u'ALLOPURINOL': 70,
                          u'ALPRAZOLAM': 20,
                          u'AMLODIPINE BESYLATE': 15,
                          u'AMLODIPINE BESYLATE-BENAZEPRIL': 24,
                          u'ATENOLOL': 62,
                          u'ATENOLOL-CHLORTHALIDONE': 53,
                          u'ATORVASTATIN CALCIUM': 19,
                          u'AZITHROMYCIN': 18}
...
...
```

So I want to get the total amount of 'ALPRAZOLAM' across the collection. I tried $group as follow:

```
{"$group": {
        "_id": "cms_prescription_counts", 
        "total": {"$sum": "I don't know what to enter here" } 
    }}
```

Anyone can help me?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Simple, Just access embedded field using **.** notation in aggregation pipeline

```
db.collection.aggregate([  
{ "$group" : { 
       "_id": "$cms_prescription_counts", 
      "total" : { "$sum" : "$cms_prescription_counts.ALPRAZOLAM"}
}}
],{allowDiskUse : true})
```

Comment: It has error Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.

Comment: I just added ,{allowDiskUse : true} in that same query, can you check now

Answer (score 0):

To sum all `ALPRAZOLAM` values, you can use [`mapReduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/) function:

```
db.yourCollection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        emit(this.cms_prescription_counts.ALPRAZOLAM); // Mapping each matching document with this item
    },
    function(keyCustId, valuesPrices) {
        return Array.sum(valuesPrices); // Sum all the values
    };
    {
         query: {}, // Filter the collection. Add your condition here
         out: "total" //  This is variable hold the total value
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to  aggregate on the column name :

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.test.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b243611dba907285af051ee"),
        "cms_prescription_counts" : {
                "ABILIFY" : 11,
                "ALLOPURINOL" : 86,
                "ALPRAZOLAM" : 45,
                "AMLODIPINE BESYLATE" : 175,
                "AMLODIPINE BESYLATE-BENAZEPRIL" : 12,
                "ATENOLOL" : 62,
                "ATENOLOL-CHLORTHALIDONE" : 53,
                "ATORVASTATIN CALCIUM" : 19,
                "AZITHROMYCIN" : 18
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b24658a853b142da9b7bd20"),
        "cms_prescription_counts" : {
                "ABILIFY" : 11,
                "ALLOPURINOL" : 70,
                "ALPRAZOLAM" : 20,
                "AMLODIPINE BESYLATE" : 15,
                "AMLODIPINE BESYLATE-BENAZEPRIL" : 24,
                "ATENOLOL" : 62,
                "ATENOLOL-CHLORTHALIDONE" : 53,
                "ATORVASTATIN CALCIUM" : 19,
                "AZITHROMYCIN" : 18
        }
}
MongoDB Enterprise > db.test.aggregate([  { $group : { "_id": "cms_prescription_counts" , "total" : { $sum : "$cms_prescription_counts.ALPRAZOLAM"}}}], { allowDiskUse: true })
{ "_id" : "cms_prescription_counts", "total" : 65 }
MongoDB Enterprise > db.test.aggregate([  { $group : { "_id": "cms_prescription_counts" , "total" : { $sum : "$cms_prescription_counts.ABILIFY"}}}],{ allowDiskUse: true })
{ "_id" : "cms_prescription_counts", "total" : 22 }
```

You need to add a a parameter `{allowDiskUse : true}`. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/).

For using with pymongo, you can refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272699/cant-get-allowdiskusetrue-to-work-with-pymongo).

Comment: I tried pipeline=[  
{ "$group" : { 
       "_id": "$cms_prescription_counts", 
      "total" : { "$sum" : "$cms_prescription_counts.ALPRAZOLAM"}
}}
]
db.pre_collection.aggregate(pipeline) but comes error

Comment: can you share the error. Its working fine on my end.

Comment: The error is Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.
BTW I use pymongo

Comment: Basically, you need to add { allowDiskUse : true } in the aggregate pipeline. When set on, this allow mongo to write temp files on disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$project : {'ALPRAZOLAM' : '$cms_prescription_counts.ALPRAZOLAM'}},
{$group:{_id:null,'total' : {$sum : '$ALPRAZOLAM'}}}
])
```