# How do i put {allowDiskUse: true} on pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have this python code:

```
import pymongo
import time
start_time = time.time()

connection_string = 'mongodb://localhost'
connection = pymongo.MongoClient(connection_string)
database = connection.solutions

pipe = [ 
  {
    '$project':{
      "_id":0
    }
  },
  {
    '$group':{
      "_id":{
        "vehicleid":"$vehicleid",
        "date":"$metrictimestamp"
      },'count':{'$sum':1}
    }
  }
         ]
query = list(database.solution1.aggregate(pipe))
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

And I'm getting this error message: **pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.**

How can I use the **allowDiskUse: true**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get allowDiskUse:True to work with pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272699/cant-get-allowdiskusetrue-to-work-with-pymongo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
query = list(database.solution1.aggregate(pipe, allowDiskUse=True))
```

Ref: [pymongo Collection level operations](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate)