# Mongo DB throws Runner error What does that mean?

Tags: mongodb

Mongo Db 2.4.6 on Windows 7 64bit throws  Runner error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 34371341 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes.

I am new to mongo and dont know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overflow sort stage buffered data usage exceeds internal limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023622/overflow-sort-stage-buffered-data-usage-exceeds-internal-limit)

Comment: I really apologize for this duplicate question. Should i delete this ?

Comment: Did the dupe in any way helped you solve your problem? If not then add more details to the question so that you can at least avoid it being closed else it would be voted as a dupe or you may delete it.

Comment: Yup, it indeed helped to solve the problem. Thanks.