# mongoDB text index on subdocuments (with dynamic structure)

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "url": "url",
    .....

    "search_elements": {

        "dynamic_value_1": {
            "text": "some text",
            ...
        },
        ...

        "dynamic_value_N": {
            "text": "other text",
             ...
        },
    },
}
```

And I want to search by 'search_elements.$.text'. Is it possible to create an index to 'search_elements.$.text'?

NOTE:

- "dynamic_value_XXX" are randomically generated when the document is created.
- Mongodb version: 2.6

Comment: No it is not possible, but you can create multikey index on array field so structure like `{ "search_elements": [ {"n" : 1, "some text"}, {"n":2, "text": "other text"}] }` can be indexed. It is rather expensive tough.

Comment: thanks, @zero323

I dinamically generate a query that `{.. sort: {"search_elements.$.text": 1}}` and I'm getting the error: "error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage"

I tried to solve using index as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023622/overflow-sort-stage-buffered-data-usage-exceeds-internal-limit). Since I cannot make this dynamic index, Is there any other possible solution to this problem without have to remodel my documents?

Comment: None I am aware off, but I don't use MongoDB much these days.