# Orion internal server error with query operation (overflow sort)

Tags: fiware-orion

Using Orion context broker, sometimes I get the following error message
when doing paginated queries (e.g. `POST /v1/queryContext?offset=3900&limit=100`):

```
 [{
   "contextElement": {
     "type": "device",
     "id": ".*",
     "isPattern": "true"}
   "statusCode": {
     "code": "500",
     "details": "Error at querying MongoDB",
     "reasonPhrase": "Internal Server Error"
   }
 }]
```

Looking into Orion log I find the following message:

> Database Error (Runner error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage
>   of 33557262 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes)

How can I solve this problem, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to existing information ([this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501937/how-to-increase-buffered-data-limit) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023622/overflow-sort-stage-buffered-data-usage-exceeds-internal-limit)), it could be due to an index is needed for the field used for sorting. Orion uses `creDate` for sorting entities result, so [creating an index](https://docs.mongodb.org/current/tutorial/create-an-index/) for that field could help, e.g.:

```
db.entities.ensureIndex( { creDate: 1 } )
```

More information about recommended indexes for Orion can be found [in the following section of the Orion manual](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/admin/perf_tuning/index.html#database-indexes).