# mongodb sort with multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, sorting

In mangoDB -3.0.7 i have created a index with 2 fields. I can run the sort on those fileds When i give only ascending/descending. Example

```
{ a: 1, b: 1 }
```

But i when i run query like,

```
{ a: 1, b: -1 }  
{ a: -1, b: 1 }
```

I am getting the following error,

```
Error: error: {
    "$err" : "Executor error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33554499 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes",
    "code" : 17144
}
```

I found this : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-and-index-prefix

How can i do this kind of sort in MongoDB. ? How to create index / any workaround for this  ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023622/overflow-sort-stage-buffered-data-usage-exceeds-internal-limit

Answer (score 0):

yes your referred link is correct

if you want to sort like this

```
{ a: 1, b: -1 }  
{ a: -1, b: 1 }
```

create  index  in this way

```
db.collection.createIndex( { { a: 1, b: -1 }   } )
```