# Mongoose-paginate: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using Mongoose, Mongoose-paginate and ExpressJS. I have this error:

> Error retrieving streams: MongoError: Runner error: Overflow sort
>   stage buffered data usage of 34227161 bytes exceeds internal limit of
>   33554432 bytes

routes.js:

```
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {

    var page = req.query.page === undefined ? 1 : req.query.page;
    var options = {
        page: page,
        limit: 30,
        sort: {
            created_at: 'desc'
        }
    };

    // https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/mongoose-paginate
    Stream.paginate(query, options, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error retrieving streams: " + err);
            errorMessage = "A problem occurred retrieving the streams";
            return res.render("streams", {
                streams: {},
                errorMessage: errorMessage
            });
        }

        return res.render("streams/list", {
            streams: result.docs,
            page: parseInt(result.page),
            pages: parseInt(result.pages)
        });
    });
});
```

How can I solve this data limit issue in Mongoose?

**EDIT:**

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023622/overflow-sort-stage-buffered-data-usage-exceeds-internal-limit), I think the size in the `data` field is getting too large, so how can I index the `data` field?

This is my model:

```
model.js:

var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');

// Declare schema
var streamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    hidden:{
        type: String
    },
    data: {
        type: Object
    }
});

streamSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);

// Export schema
// Model.paginate()
mongoose.model("Stream", streamSchema);
```

Can I **ignore** the `data` field when I **query the list of the streams**?

**EDIT 2:**

With this solution:

```
db.mydb.ensureIndex({created_at: 1})
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : true,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I still get the same error...

**EDIT 3:**

Found the answer to exclude fields:

```
var options = {
    page: page,
    limit: 30,
    sort: {
        created_at: 'desc'
    },
    select: '-data'
};
```

I still get the same error...

Comment: See here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023622/overflow-sort-stage-buffered-data-usage-exceeds-internal-limit

You can try indexing the created_at field.

Comment: @dyouberg I have seen that answer but how can I `Indexing the sort field`??

Answer (score 3):

You are running into the 32 MB limit of sorting in memory.

You want to create an index so MongoDB does the sorting for you.

Run the following command in your MongoDB Shell:

```
db.collectionName.ensureIndex({created_at: 1})
```

See here for more information:
[Overflow sort stage buffered data usage exceeds internal limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023622/overflow-sort-stage-buffered-data-usage-exceeds-internal-limit)

Edit: To project out a field in your response you do it as follows:

```
db.collection.find({}, {field_to_see: 1, field_to_hide: 0})
```

Read here: [MongoDB Explicit Exclusion](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/#explicitly-excluded-fields)

Comment: how can I ignore a field when I query the streams? please see my edit above. thanks.

Comment: `db.collectionName.ensureIndex({created_at: 1})` what does this do?

Comment: It tells MongoDB to sort your collection by that field so it can query your data faster, and avoid sorting it in memory whenever possible.

Comment: thanks for the edit. the problem is i am using `mongoose-paginate` - how can I use `db.collection.find({}, {field_to_see: 1, field_to_hide: 0})` in that?

Comment: `Stream.paginate(query, options, function(err, result) {` this is how I query and paginate the streams.

Comment: Found the answer to exclude fields but still having the same error... any ideas what other reasons??

Comment: What are your options defined as?  You are using Mongoose Paginate for some reason, which has different syntax than Mongoose does.

See here: https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/mongoose-paginate#more-advanced-example

Comment: `What are your options defined as?` sorry what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - must add `index: 1` to the model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');

// Declare schema
var streamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    hidden:{
        type: String
    },
    data: {
        type: Object
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        index: 1
    },
});

streamSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);

// Export schema
// Model.paginate()
mongoose.model("Stream", streamSchema);
```

Then:

```
mongo> db.mydb.ensureIndex({created_at: 1})
```

Answer (score -1):

Use cursor to stream datas for big dataset :

```
var findCursor = Stream.find(query).cursor();
findCursor.on("data", function(data) {
  // datas...
});
findCursor.on("end", function(){
 // end of the stream
});
```

Comment: how can I ignore a field when I query the streams? please see my edit above. thanks.

Comment: To ignore field, use the project field :

 Stream.find(query, { data:0})   see https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/