# MongoError: OperationFailed: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM

Tags: mongodb, sorting, meteor

I am using Meteor 1.5 with MongoDB shell version: 3.2.12. 
I have around 42000 users in my database.
I have made a subscription of showing these users and their information for admin.
I show 20 records/users per page.

When I visit page number 1964, I get this exception in server console:

**Exception from sub allUsers id SzTYWKd8mK77ybWw2 MongoError: Executor error during find command: OperationFailed: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.**

Here is the code for a subscription:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('allUsers', function(options, queryParams) {

  try{

    if(serverHelperClass.isAdmin(this.userId)){ 

      return {

        find: function() {

            return Meteor.users.find(
              {}, 
              { 
                fields: {_id: 1, createdAt: 1, emails: 1, lastUpdated: 1, 'profile.firstName': 1, 'profile.lastName': 1 },
                limit: 20, skip: 39260, sort: { 'lastUpdated.timeStamp': -1 } 
            });
        }
      };
    }
    return {find:function(){return Meteor.users.find({_id:''});}}; 
  }
  catch (e) {serverHelperClass.throwLog('subscription: allUsersPaginated: '+e.stack, e);}
});
```

Also I feel like this is happening because of the sorting. Do I need to create some index for sorting?

Comment: Take a look at here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023622/overflow-sort-stage-buffered-data-usage-exceeds-internal-limit/44721920#44721920