# Proper Indexes for mLab Mongo DB Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mlab

I have a mongo db running on mLab.  Some queries (via parse-server) are failing with the following error:

```
OperationFailed: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 
bytes of RAM [duplicate]
```

I have seen other questions on SO similar to this ([such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023622/overflow-sort-stage-buffered-data-usage-exceeds-internal-limit)) and I've followed their advice to add indexes.  However, this error persists. I am curious if my indexes are doing what I need them to do or if I need to add additional/better indexes or pursue another solution.

Here are my indexes:

```
INDEXED FIELD(S)    UNIQUE  SPARSE  TTL SIZE

{ "_created_at": -1, "email": 1 }   (false) (false) -   268.00 KB   
{ "_id": 1 }    (true)  (false) -   216.00 KB   
{ "appName": 1, "email": 1, "isDeleted": 1, "_rperm": 1, "reportDate": -1 } (false) (false) -   140.00 KB   
{ "appname": 1, "_rperm": 1 }   (false) (false) -   60.00 KB    
{ "email": 1, "_created_at": -1 }   (false) (false) -   132.00 KB   
{ "email": 1 }  (false) (false) -   88.00 KB    
{ "isDeleted": -1, "_created_at": -1 }  (false) (false) -   116.00 KB
{ "reportDate": -1 }    (false) (false) -   4.00 KB
```

And here is an offending query from the mLab profiler:

```
{
"op": "query",
"ns": "REDACTED.Farm",
"query": {
    "find": "Farm",
    "filter": {
        "$or": [
            {
                "appName": "REDACTED",
                "email": "REDACTED@REDACTED.com",
                "isDeleted": false,
                "_rperm": {
                    "$in": [
                        null,
                        "*",
                        "REDACTED"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "appName": "any",
                "email": "REDACTED",
                "isDeleted": false,
                "_rperm": {
                    "$in": [
                        null,
                        "*",
                        "REDACTED"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "sort": {
        "reportDate": -1
    },
    "projection": {
        "name": 1,
        "propertyCount": 1,
        "reportDate": 1,
        "turnoverRate": 1,
        "_id": 1,
        "_created_at": 1,
        "_updated_at": 1
    },
    "limit": 100
},
"numYield": 0,
"locks": {
    "Global": {
        "acquireCount": {
            "r": 2
        }
    },
    "Database": {
        "acquireCount": {
            "r": 1
        }
    },
    "Collection": {
        "acquireCount": {
            "r": 1
        }
    }
},
"responseLength": 249,
"protocol": "op_query",
"millis": 7,
"planSummary": "IXSCAN { appName: 1, email: 1, isDeleted: 1, _rperm: 1, reportDate: -1 }, IXSCAN { appName: 1, email: 1, isDeleted: 1, _rperm: 1, reportDate: -1 }",
"ts": {
    "$date": "2018-03-01T16:50:25.550Z"
},
"client": "54.166.17.32",
"allUsers": [
    {
        "user": "REDACTED",
        "db": "REDACTED"
    }
],
"user": "MY_REDACTED_USER"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the query is using an index (`{ "appName": 1, "email": 1, "isDeleted": 1, "_rperm": 1, "reportDate": -1 }`) that includes the sort field, MongoDB is still performing an in-memory sort. The order of fields in the index is preventing MongoDB from using the index to sort.

Query fields which use `$in` should be included in your index after the fields on which you sort. So `_rperm` should be after `reportedDate`. Try this index instead:

```
{ "appName": 1, "email": 1, "isDeleted": 1, "reportDate": -1, "_rperm": 1 }
```

You can read more about how to order fields in indexes here: http://docs.mlab.com/indexing/#determining-the-order-of-fields