# How to set internalQueryExecMaxBlockingSortBytes in mongo.conf

Tags: mongodb, memory-management

I'm having trouble finding out how to set `internalQueryExecMaxBlockingSortBytes` in my mongo configuration file.

I have been coming up against the following error message:

> OperationFailure: Executor error during find command: OperationFailed:
>   Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add
>   an index, or specify a smaller limit.

I'm not sure why it says set a *smaller* limit, I would think that I want to *increase* the limit. I have seen that I can set the parameter manually as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38408403/6084948) with the following command:

```
>  db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, internalQueryExecMaxBlockingSortBytes:50151432})
{ "was" : 33554432, "ok" : 1 }
```

I'm using the following versions of Mongo:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
MongoDB server version: 3.4.10
```

In looking at the documentation, I see no mention of `internalQueryExecMaxBlockingSortBytes`. I assume that I could set this parameter using `setParameter`:

```
setParameter:
   internalQueryExecMaxBlockingSortBytes: 67108864
```

But this option is not mentioned in https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/parameters/. Is the setting from another version of Mongo? Can I use it with v3.4?

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23768 says
This is yaml formatting is documented here and the documented parameters are listed here. The reason it is not specifically documented is that it is not a part of the public MongoDB API and we don't want to commit to supporting it in all future versions, which is why it is prefixed with "internal". The aggregation pipeline already supports spilling external sorts to disk and there is an open feature request to extend this functionality to the regular query: SERVER-7694.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's really late to answer. But today I also faced the same issue, and through lots of searches, I got the answer. I thought it will help someone someday.

`db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes: 67108864})`
Use this command to set the RAM size. Perform this command on the admin database. otherwise, it will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old post but i think it can help to late comers as me:

You should append below text to your /etc/mongod.conf (if your OS is linux)

setParameter:
: 
...

[Source](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/)